# How resolve gnuplot artifacts in heat map

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap

I'm trying to generate a heat map from data (https://pastebin.com/AgivvGgX). The data are not in the "matrix" form.

I tried to use `pm3d map` and I obtained the following plot:
[image]

I also tried to use `dgrid3d` and `view map`:

```
set view map
set pal def
set dgrid3d 40,40,3
splot "plot.dat" using 1:2:3 u pm3d
```

And I obtained the following result:
[image]

Both the plots are not correct. The `dgird3d` keyword creates artifacts where there are not data points.

I obtained a nice plot using the code:

```
set view map
set pal def
splot "plot.dat" using 1:2:3 with points pointtype 5 pointsize 1 palette   linewidth 8
```

Here the result
[image]

I would like to obtain a map similar to the latter one, but not with discrete points or squares but as a continuous heat map and have a white background where data are not present. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Since your data is irregular, you should use `dgrid3d`. It has various options (see `help dgrid3d`), here is a picture I've got while trying different kernels and options:

```
set view map
set palette defined (0 'white', 1 'blue', 2 'green', 3 'yellow', 4 'red')
set dgrid3d 100,100 exp kdensity 10,10
splot 'plot.dat' w pm3d palette
```

[image]

```
set dgrid3d 100,100 gauss kdensity 30,30
replot
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. The original data ranges from `0 to 65` but the `cbrange` of the plots are now `0 to 120` and `<50 to 400`. How to "rescale" properly depending on the `kdensity` values? And how to distinguish between existing values `=0` and missing values? The latter now look like as they would be `0`.

Comment: Thank you. I obtained different color code between values equal to zero and missing value using the option: `set dgrid3d 100,100 hann` or `set dgrid3d 100,100 box`